# Kotlin - Deserializing with Jackson XmlMapper

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm having some trouble to parse correctly an XML file with Jackson XML Mapper.
Suppose I have this simple XML:

```
<Test>
    <Simple>
        <x>I am x</x>
        <y>I am y</y>
    </Simple>
</Test>
```

and this simple class:

```
@Root(name="Simple",strict = false)
class Simple {

    @Element(name = "x", required = false)
    lateinit var x :String

    @Element(name = "y", required = false)
    lateinit var y :String
    
}
```

The compiler keeps throwing this error:

`Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Simple" (class Simple), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "x", "y"])`

I guess it's because Kotlin can't find the proper structure of the file within the class?
Problem is I need to parse a much more big xml file, and need to avoid to mirror every single Element of the xml, otherwise it will become huge.

So how can I "partially" parse the xml, setting the root to the `<Simple>` tag, avoiding the `<Test>` tag?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working solution. Note that I've made the mapper case insensitive to cope with the capitalised Simple property in the XML. You could do this with an annotation on the property instead to override the default lower case name. Note also the use of data classes that do away with any need to use lateinit vars or suchlike:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.JacksonXmlModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.registerKotlinModule


data class Simple(val x: String, val y: String)
data class Test(val simple: Simple)


fun main() {

    val xmlDeserializer = XmlMapper(JacksonXmlModule().apply {
        setDefaultUseWrapper(false)
    }).registerKotlinModule()
        .configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true)
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

    val simple = Simple("x","y")
    val test = Test(simple)
    println(xmlDeserializer.writeValueAsString(test))

    val stringToParse = "<Test><Simple><x>1</x><y>2</y></Simple></Test>"
    val finalObject = xmlDeserializer.readValue(stringToParse, Test::class.java)
    println(finalObject.simple.x)
}
```

make sure your build.gradle.kts has these dependencies if they aren't there already:

```
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.13.1")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.13.1")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried as you suggested but I get a `lateinit propery not initialized error`. Can you help me understand why? This is the [code](https://ibb.co/74YjW2g)

Comment: Please post the code here, as per stackoverflow guidelines (your best bet is to edit the original question) rather than posting it on an external site. I can see what the problem is, but it needs to be posted here :)

Comment: Can you post your grade file too, makes it easier to test at this end?

Comment: Edited original question :) Many many thanks!

Comment: replace the `lateinit var` with `val` in all cases. You don't need `lateinit` as Jackson is written in Java. It will just call the default constructor followed by the setters.

Comment: Full working solution added.

Comment: Solution seen, I thank you so much for making this work. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Can you mark the answer as correct on here please ?